# What are the best practices for making xhr requests in 2018

Tags: javascript, http

i would like to create my own framework to help me fully understand javascript  language. After searching for the best option to make requests i have found a number of ways to contact a server and ask it for data.

What are the best practices for making xhr requests in 2018.

Comment: You should now use Fetch API which is more concise than XHR, in 2018.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure on best practises, I guess that's a varied subject. But I recommend checking out [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) and its features, as it's my go-to for any XHR work.

My favourite features:

- Uses `es6`
- Use `Promises`
- Browser compatibility
- Ability to hook into `interceptors` which you can use to run code on every `request` (to the server) and `response` (from the server). For instance:

  > if (error.response.status === 422) { showErrorAlert(); }
- Can spin up a many instances: global instance with `interceptors` which apply to all requests, but can also setup separate instances of axios, which could use a different set of `interceptors`
- Ability to cancel requests
- Transforms responses automatically to JSON